# CakePHP: How to lookup related field values from view

Tags: cakephp

I understand MVC a bit, but I am new to CakePHP.  My question is simple I think, but no matter how many ways I have tried, I am not able to retrieve the data I am looking for.

Lets start with 2 Models: Users and Activities. 
User -- (Has Many Activities)
-id
-name

Activity (Belongs to Users)
-id
-user_id (related to uses's id)
-created_by (related to uses's id)

Now, in my Activities views, the user_id and created_by both show up with User Name...which is what I want, but in my User view.cpt bake gave me a section under the User info that lists the activities associated with the user I am viewing, but in this list, only the User's IDs show up.

Here is the baked code in my Users/view.cpt

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($user['Activity'] as $activity): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $activity['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['user_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['created_by']; ?></td> //I Want the User's NAME not iD
        <td><?php echo $activity['due_date']; ?></td>   //I Want the User's NAME not iD
        <td><?php echo $activity['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['modified']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['cfc_id']; ?></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'view', $activity['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'edit', $activity['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'delete', $activity['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $activity['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know I am going to have to do this all over the place (Because all my models will be based on a User) what is the proper way of retreiving this data.  I have tried adding methods to the model and User/Activity controllers, but I can't seem to access the methods correct.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `Activity.php` model class:

```
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User',
                      'foreignKey' => 'user_id'),
              'Creator' => array('className' => 'User',
                         'foreignKey' => 'created_by'));
```

In controller's class method:

```
$this->Activity->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Activity.user_id' => $user_id)));
```

In your view file:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($user['Activity'] as $activity): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $activity['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['User']['username']; ?></td> //username is the name of user
        <td><?php echo $activity['Creator']['username']; ?></td> //username is the name of user
        <td><?php echo $activity['due_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['modified']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $activity['cfc_id']; ?></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'view', $activity['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'edit', $activity['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'delete', $activity['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $activity['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the same Belongs to code, but when I use the $activity['User']['name'] code, I get the error "Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/View/Users/view.ctp, line 76]"

Comment: The issue is that I'm in the UsersController View.ctp, and when I look at the Arrays of data available, I get the User (the current user i'm viewing) and the associated Activities that the users has, both by Owner, and Creator. But that array does not then go down and loop back through the associated User for the Activitie's created_by and user_id. Which is how I would get the Name.  But if this happened, wouldn't that generate an infinite loop? So how else can I get the name? Call a method from the view to the controller to lockup usernames?